# Ubuntu Firefox. How to get the css javascript files of the currently loaded website?

Tags: javascript, linux, firefox, caching, ubuntu

I have a stupid problem. I have created a Website and unfortunately completely destroyed the the js and css files. The only correct version of my website is in my FireFox Browser. But when I try to save the files from my browser I get the destroyed version of files, but I know that the browser has also the correct version somewhere in cache or somewhere else, because the functionality of the currently loaded page is as expected from non-destroyed files.

Please help me.

Comment: This will hopefully not destroy your cached files (as suggested in answers below: backup first), but did you try 'view source' and then clicking on the link to the js file?

Comment: I guess a comment on using a version control system for your source code would be a bit redundant here...

Comment: Nail, I get the destroyed file, not the cached.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), but I'd create a backup of your Firefox profile before you  try anything else.

UPDATE

If you can't see the files in the about:cache memory cache section, then I'm surprised they are still being used by the page. Are you sure?

You may be able to get some of the javascript source code back by going to the Console Panel in firebug and executing the line `""+my_function_name` where my_function_name is the name of a function you remember writing. The css should all be in the CSS Panel (that is always a representation of the CSS currently rendered), though not in it's original form.

Comment: firebug requires reload of javascript. I need the real copy of the javascript file. but I can not find it.

Comment: Use the HTML panel, not the script panel, and inspect the script tag in the HTML.

Comment: How to enable this panel? thanks

Comment: If you have firebug installed press f12 and it will appear in the bottom section of the window. panels will be titled 'Console', 'HTML', 'CSS', 'Script' and so on. click on the HTML one, expand head, and then expand your js/css files.

Comment: Ok, I dit it, but unfortunately got the destoyed js file. But the working copy is still in the Firefox and js is working there. Any suggestions?

Comment: Go to the url `about:cache` and click `List Cache Entries` under `Disk Cache` or `Memory Cache`. But if it works give @Jeremy the credit!

Comment: I tried it, but there are no needed files in the list. I think it is in the RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Use this: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cacheviewer-continued/

Comment: it wants me to restart firefox to enable this extensuion. but thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you could have destroyed your cached files when trying to save them.

But first thing you should do now is backup your `~/.mozilla/firefox` directory - if something is cached then it should be there.

Answer (score 0):

Go to about:cache in firefox. That should list where your cache is on disk, and from there you can find you JS and CSS files.

Comment: It shows me "List Cache Entries" but there is none of my files I need.  It also doesn't show the location where it is stored. Perhaps an other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://www.ehow.com/how_8282401_cache-file-mozilla-firefox.html) can come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

Just go offline. Firefox won't change the cache once you do this, and you can safely save anything that you can find.